# Netbeans is slow on macOS

Tags: macos, netbeans, macos-sierra, netbeans-8

I need some suggestions for my IDE's performance.
Before I switched all my computers / notebooks to Apple, NetBeans works very well.

After switching to Apple NetBeans is working very bad. It takes a lot of time to start, end working with remote ftp is very very slow. (Remote FTP with upload on save) - For a file of 200KB it takes up to a minute to upload it.
Aso opening files is very slow. Dont't using any plugins.

I'm using the newest JDK.

My iMac is late 2014 (5K display, 32GB RAM, 1TB FusionDrive). I hope you have some suggestions to speed up my IDE. If you need logs, just tell me.

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249391

Comment: Thanks, but scrolling is not a problem of mine. I used the newest JDK.

Comment: Did you try to increase java heap space (Xms and Xmx)? It helped me on my performance issues on my MacBook Pro

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: I increased, but also slow as everytime...